# PyCharm export multiple df's to a single csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, pandas.excelwriter

I'm moving my code across the PyCharm.     My code has fallen over on the   ExcelWriter method of Pandas.     Is the export of multiple dataframes to a   csv not   possible in pyCharm?

```
        excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Out_RFQ_Status_1_' + REGION + '.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31, 32, 33, 34]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

SOURCE: [ExcelWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)

Comment: Hey @Vishnudev, I updated the line to excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Out_RFQ_Status_1_' + REGION + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter'). I'm getting this error in PyCharm:

    import xlsxwriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

Is there an additional package I need to add to PyCharm?

Comment: I'll just add I have no issue in Jupyter Notebook, just running the code in PyCharm raises the error

Comment: Working now. Installed XlsxWriter. Thanks @Vishnudev